# converting a string to unicode in c on linux platform

Tags: c, sms, sms-gateway, smpp, telecommunication

I need to convert the string to utf-8. How this can be done on linux platfom.
Suppose string is "c3aa" it should be encoded to "ê". As i need it to implement it for vcard
My vcard string contains :

```
BEGIN:VCARD^M
VERSION:2.1^M
N;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:;=C3=AA=74=65=64;;;^M
FN;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTAABLE:=C3=AA=74=65=64^M
TEL;CELL;PREF:75501945^M
END:VCARD^M
```

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance

Comment: UTF-8 is the default Unicode encoding for `char` stuff these days (assuming your environment is set up properly).  You just need to decode the string.

Comment: but how to decode it?

Comment: A big clue is `ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE`, described in [RFC 2045](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt).